# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Tags: extensions, error, admin-panel

After installing "sphinx search ultimate", when I goto the config page and select the "sphinx search" panel, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 464
```

I've tried some of the tips mentioned on the site here, including ensuring compilation is off.. but no luck.

Can someone help? Have you ever seen this issue when installing a new extension? Ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all the files are installed, and web server has enough privileges to actually load them. This could easily happens if install requires several steps. toOptionArray is a method from object that populates drop-down options. Referring to it as a non-object means that the object value is null, which usually happens when declaration file is either missing or not readable.

Comment: thanks. In the end, the extension makers sorted it out for me. Did seems to be a bad install or something.

Answer (score 4):

copy `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php`

paste / extend to / create `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php`

find the following on line 463

```
$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
```

and replace it with:

```
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
   $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
} else {
   Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practices to modifiy the core.

Comment: Hi @Nolwennig just paste / extend to / create app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php

Comment: Helps to get the issue. Thanks for the trick.